# Apache 2 Virtual Host allow serving all files from a directory

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, node.js, apache-virtualhost, http-proxy

I have an Apache 2 server installed on my Debian system. The Apache listens on port 80. Then I have a simple nodeJS server listening on port 8080. I want to use the Apache as proxy for the nodeJS server. What I have so far:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia Full
        <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        <Location />
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
        </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Then I have the nodeJS server in `/var/www/html/nodejs/app.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/second', function(req, res){  
    res.sendFile('/var/www/html/nodejs/public/second.html');
});

app.listen(port, function() { 
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)
});

app.use(express.static("/var/www/html/nodejs/public"));
```

and in my `/var/www/html/nodejs/public` directory I have my static files `index.html`, `second.html` and `myScript.js`

Now... My problem is: if I access the webpage via http://localhost:8080 (i.e. directly without the apache proxy) it works just fine. But on http://localhost:80 (i.e. the apache proxy), it serves me only the `index.html` file. The other two files are not served and Chrome Network tab shows `Status: 502 Proxy Error` for them.

So my question is, how can I make it so the Apache proxy sees all these files from `public` directory so it can send them to my browser? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try to add an additional slash at the end of you ProxyPass, like:

```
ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

?

Comment: holy **** this worked... And to think I spent several hours trying to figure this out. Just to clarify, without the extra `/` I was trying to get `http://localhost:80second.html` instead of `http://localhost:80/second.html`?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what was taking place here.